# How do I find out when I can ask another question?

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting

I've been a greedy piggy and asked lots of questions, and now I'm getting this message:

> You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period.

Other than counting the messages over the past 30 days, is there some way of finding out when I can start posting again?

Comment: Nope. There is no indicator; count up to 50 and see how long ago #50 on the list was.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok thanks :)

Comment: If you didn't delete any questions, by my count #50 was posted at oct 7 at 18:06.

Comment: @MartijnPieters might have deleted one or two. That's why I was asking here because by looking back it's not always apparent...

Comment: That's more than 30 days ago @MartijnPieters...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: See my answer below; it means there are deleted questions and my reckoning cannot be accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such indicator.

Count the questions manually (they are listed per 30 on your questions page), and add 30 days to the oldest question. Take into account any you deleted recently (there is a link at the bottom of the questions page, listing questions you deleted in the past 60 days).

The posting timestamp of question #50 + 30 days is the moment you can ask again.

If you didn't delete any questions, by my reckoning question #50 was posted on October 7th, at 18:06, which means you must've deleted at least one question to be still rate limited. The next one was posted on October 13th, at 23:50 UTC, meaning that if you deleted just one question in the past 30 days, you should be able to ask a question again on November 13th (give or take 10 minutes).